# appIdentityService.signForApp (Java) and app_identity.sign_blob (Python) results are different

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-identity

I need to sign JWT using Google Cloud appIdentity.

I tried using python agent and it is working. But the Java client gives signature error. 
So I run test code to get signature of same input from Java and Python. It returns different result.

python code

```
import array
from google.appengine.api import app_identity

header_and_payload = "test"
(key_name, signature) = app_identity.sign_blob(header_and_payload)
print array.array('B', signature)
```

java code

```
import com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityService;
import com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceFactory;

headerAndPayload = "test";
AppIdentityService appIdentityService = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();
AppIdentityService.SigningResult signingResult = appIdentityService.signForApp(headerAndPayload.getBytes());

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(signingResult.getSignature()));
```

Python output

```
[205, 130, 214, 28, 19, 7, 233, 69, 92, 161, 8, 160, 36, 162, 149, 125, 5, 100, 8, 219, 244, 235, 188, 126, 118, 45, 176, 63, 61, 88, 91, 151, 151, 114, 228, 31, 85, 209, 117, 134, 66, 120, 13, 159, 10, 155, 70, 16, 110, 56, 212, 79, 165, 40, 222, 46, 26, 74, 182, 80, 223, 57, 244, 44, 224, 122, 230, 184, 114, 236, 158, 204, 145, 152, 133, 131, 115, 43, 224, 132, 219, 232, 186, 237, 82, 86, 243, 194, 155, 127, 26, 227, 19, 165, 142, 216, 238, 163, 99, 251, 41, 191, 164, 206, 85, 239, 64, 133, 41, 49, 120, 235, 120, 226, 96, 224, 105, 68, 81, 186, 184, 65, 233, 129, 211, 231, 211, 135, 15, 88, 35, 20, 217, 95, 56, 215, 134, 71, 210, 28, 43, 22, 231, 69, 134, 116, 227, 161, 202, 94, 54, 222, 132, 158, 108, 45, 73, 68, 240, 90, 59, 139, 222, 118, 6, 82, 162, 198, 143, 7, 233, 148, 233, 232, 101, 135, 182, 71, 148, 136, 246, 168, 5, 28, 94, 11, 10, 78, 147, 4, 200, 36, 79, 244, 117, 223, 114, 33, 2, 206, 13, 66, 204, 201, 102, 147, 237, 83, 83, 17, 221, 16, 136, 206, 115, 141, 32, 149, 131, 136, 183, 96, 51, 31, 212, 174, 245, 120, 18, 120, 191, 174, 90, 111, 122, 136, 96, 152, 81, 8, 72, 52, 33, 46, 227, 241, 41, 77, 40, 176, 97, 189, 195, 197, 202, 71]
```

java output

```
[10, -64, 92, 105, 15, 35, -32, -101, 47, 111, -1, -72, 110, 105, -77, -117, 23, 69, 113, -49, -14, -104, 110, 78, 84, -78, 30, 26, 38, -43, 36, 112, 33, -10, -5, -63, -11, 47, -53, -116, -71, 2, -64, -16, 36, 122, 45, 79, 3, 49, -7, 120, -10, 125, 92, 43, -43, -34, 100, 75, -54, -36, 5, 106, -128, 106, -120, 36, 59, -31, -2, 100, 79, 65, -118, -50, -83, 11, -19, -28, -80, -125, -8, 59, -94, -125, 91, -104, -96, -12, 14, 31, -108, 61, 12, 6, 90, -6, -24, -47, -57, 55, -64, -50, 41, 26, -46, -81, -124, 122, 82, -120, 31, 19, 85, -7, -17, 40, -18, -118, -64, 114, -76, -60, 116, -12, -16, 12, -91, 55, -57, -61, 108, 88, -13, 80, -38, 100, 121, -11, -20, -5, -105, 20, 87, 60, -125, 33, -11, 111, -115, -69, 24, 0, -113, -24, 49, 21, -27, 96, 27, 12, 72, 50, 12, 15, -61, -40, -52, -76, -63, 29, -99, 114, 88, 41, 111, 9, 127, 96, -123, 58, 92, -91, 17, 114, -11, -105, -79, -110, -100, -35, 16, 103, 27, -21, -50, 7, -28, 117, 119, -124, -127, -115, -116, 86, 74, 57, -46, 114, 102, -18, -73, 97, 10, -113, 119, -1, -68, -18, -16, -119, 49, -120, 104, 121, 113, -82, -42, -119, -81, 95, -114, 16, -11, -58, 36, -24, 58, -50, 101, -117, -55, -101, -19, 62, -53, 30, -59, 106, 37, 98, 102, 75, -9, 91]
```

What is the issue in Java code? Thank you.

Comment: In the line `print array.array('B', signature)` you are using the option 'B' for unsigned char according to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html). If you use the option 'b' (for signed char) like in `print array.array('b', signature)` you will get the same results for both the Java and the python versions.

Comment: Have you solved the issue yet?

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
print array.array('B', signature)
```

you are using the option `'B'` for unsigned char according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html). If you use the option `'b'` (for signed char) like in

```
print array.array('b', signature)
```

you will get the same results for both the Java and the python versions.

I performed tests with the sample codes for [Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/appidentity/#asserting_identity_to_third-party_services) and [Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/appidentity/#asserting_identity_to_third-party_services). In the Python example I set the message variable to the same value as in Java:

```
message = "abcdefg"
```

and added this line:

```
self.response.write('Signature Array: {}\n'.format(array.array('b', signature)))
```

Hope this helps.